# React Native Navigation view list of screens

Tags: react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm currently using the react native navigation library. I'm having trouble debugging certain issues and I want to know :

- how do you view the stack of screens that are currently pushed?
- when you have cascading modals, how do you view their order and do the modal instances have a unique ID?

Answer (score 1):

In case your are using react navigation with redux. You can locate them in the debugger tools which also gives you the order and the unique ID.[image]

something like this.

*edit for your comment*:

you can watch for state change in redux to determine the current screen. I guess there is no getCurrentScreen. React navigation provides callback for  state change which you could use.

```
    onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, newState) => {
      // your code to determine screen
    })
```

Comment: so there is no 'getRoutes' ? .. no getCurrentScreenName? ... and so?

Comment: Yes. It helps. I do not will use anymore this library again